# Grails/Groovy mock dynamic properties for third party objects

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

```
def client = new SOAPClient("http://...")
def response = client.send(
    """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
       <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
           <soap-env:Body>
               <GetFoo>bar</GetFoo>
           </soap-env:Body>
       </soap-env:Envelope>"""
)
return response.xmlElement1.xmlElement2.xmlElement3.text()
```

This is a piece of service code in my project. def response is a WsLite library's object called HTTPResponse.

In my unit tests, I want to mock this response as part of this code:

```
def mockClient = Mock(SOAPClient)
        mockClient.send(XML_REQUEST) >> createMockResponse()
```

I am not quite sure how should I mock this response object and populate some expected values.

For example, mock response with `response.xmlElement1.xmlElement2.xmlElement3.text()` is 'ABC'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stub the response to return map with the expected pattern of return value

```
mockClient.send(XML_REQUEST) >> {
    [ xmlElement1: [ xmlElement2: [ xmlElement3: [ text : { 'ABC' } ] ] ] ]
}

assert response.xmlElement1.xmlElement2.xmlElement3.text() == 'ABC'
```